What does "気持ちの置き場" mean?
嬉しいけど気持ちの置き場がわからない。　友達だからってそこまでする？
The character is thinking this as her crush is helping her and doing stuff for her. Naturally she's happy but wonders if she crush would do such length for a friend?
However I'm confused, what does 気持ちの置き場 mean? Is she talking about her own feeling? Or the nature of the other's feeling? according to google it seems a common way of saying?

In addition to naruto’s answer, I think it is worth mentioning that (気持ちの)やり場 is often used to mean the same and thus it is a better foothold to look for further information about the expression. (気持ちの)置き場 is probably a less common variation of that.

By saying 気持ちの置き場が分からない, she is talking about her own situation. Essentially, she is saying "I don't know what to do with my feelings" or "My emotions are unsettled". That is, while her "raw" emotions are happy, she doesn't know whether she can simply feel happy or should be suspicious about her crush's kindness.
気持ちの置き場 literally means "the place to put one's feelings". I'm not sure if it's common enough to be called a set phrase, but I think its meaning is self-explanatory. It refers not to her initial feeling, but to how to make sense of or deal with it.

How did you know it was not the crush's feelings?

@BigRigz If the sentence were 気持ちが分からない, that would be 彼の気持ちが分からない ("I don't understand his feelings"). However, 彼の気持ちの置き場が分からない ("I don't know how to put his feelings") doesn't make sense.

...It makes sense to me: "How he places his emotions [on the matter]."

I assumed this was a lesbian relationship based on the OP's use of pronouns.

@BigRigz 彼の気持ちの置き場が(私に)分からない would mean "He appears to be really confused and I don't know how he can deal with his emotions", but nothing indicates this. It's clearly the girl herself who is confused here.

Oh! So "he does not understand his place of emotions" is not what the speaker is implying here, since Japanese typically does not allow for one to judge another's feelings without using a grammar form. Is this correct? The end goal of this all is I will delete my response, but I just want to make sure I understand why I am wrong. In other words, it is wrong to interpret that the speaker is talking about the other person because that would require clarifying grammar?

@BigRigz The subject of "understand" is clearly "I". "He does not understand" is 彼は分かっていない, not 彼は分からない, if that's what you mean.

Can you link a stack exchange post that explains this nuance? I have never encountered this use of ている.

@BigRigz Does this help? "彼は分からない" sounds like "He will never understand it" rather than "He doesn't understand it (right now)".
